# jquery form plugin is not showing current server response(image),but it displays the previous response(image) in firefox,opera and safari

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

i am using jquery form plugin(version: 3.31.0-2013.03.27) and PHP to develop a site.I basically use jquery form plugin to submit image into the server,the server processes the image and sends it back to the browser. Till now everything is fine! But the problem arises once i upload a new image,the browser ends up just displaying the previously uploaded image. SERVER side is ok,it gets the new image and stores in file system.The code does well in Google Chrome without a problem,but firefox,opera and safari are showing the previously uploaded image. My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#UploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#SubmitButton').attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
                //show uploading message
                $("#output").html('<div style="padding:10px"><img src="pic/ajax-loader2.gif" alt="Please Wait"/> <span>Uploading...</span></div>');
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    target: '#output',
                    success:  afterSuccess //call function after success
                });
            });
        });
```

Any HELP is appreciated! Thnkss in Advance!!!

Comment: I think your problem is the caching. try to change the image's url to the new image in "Success"

Comment: Thank you Brosel for your quick response. But I still don't get you.Could you please explain on how I do it? :)